# Stickysidebar within container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

Affix is giving me a hard time. I'm trying to create a sticky sidebar that only follows within the bounds of the container.

The sidebar should stick to the top of the screen as long as it's within the containing div.

See my horrible attempt here: http://codepen.io/icedice/pen/OMrPwz

I'm using `$('#sidebar').affix();`

Is this possible with affix or how do i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the offset.bottom option so that `affix-bottom` gets set on the sidebar...

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
    offset: {
      top: ..,
      bottom: ..
    }
});
```

http://codeply.com/go/sv7l3DDGtO

Comment: Yes. This looks very nice. now I just need to make sure that everything over and under the the content is within one single div (one over one under) so i can calc the offset. Thanks a lot.